# How to reshape daily time series data into a table using R?

Tags: r, reshape

I have daily rainfall data for 43 years. The data is in DD/MM/YYYY format. The start date is 01/01/1978 and the end date is 31/12/2020. I want to reshape/rearrange this data into a table (365 (rows - number of days in a year) x 43 (columns - years of data record)) such that the first day of each data year starts on April 1st and ends on March 31st of the next year (for example, the data year 1978-1979 start from 01/04/1978 and end on 31/03/1979).

Expected table format is:

[image]

How to write R code for this? I'm new to R.

Comment: What should happen with 1980-02-29, 1984-02-29, 1988-02-29, ... when you only have 365 days?

Comment: During leap years, all 366 days should be included in the respective columns, which means, columns containing values in normal years will have 365 rows but during leap years will have 366 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This code is admittedly ugly so I am more than willing to take suggestions for improvements.
This solution requires `dplyr` and `lubridate` that are both in the `tidyverse`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
start_date <- dmy("01/01/1978")
end_date <- dmy("31/12/2020")

# Generate dummy dataset
dates <- as_date(start_date:end_date)
observations <- runif(length(dates), 1, 13)
df <- tibble(dates, observations)

df %>% 
  # Create a column "dyear" for the data year.
  mutate(
    dyear = paste(
      floor(quarter(dates, type = "year.quarter", fiscal_start = 4)) - 1,
      ceiling(quarter(dates, type = "year.quarter", fiscal_start = 4)) - 1,
      sep = "-"
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(dyear) %>% 
  # Hacky method to get the right numbers for day of year.
  mutate(yday = if_else(
    dyear == "1977-1978",
    as.integer(yday(dates) + (interval(dmy("01/04/1977"), start_date) %/% days(1))),
    row_number()
  )) %>%
  select(-dates) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = dyear, values_from = observations, id_expand = T)
```

I wish `yday` and `year` had a `fiscal_start` option, but it seems [that won't be the case](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/947).
Either way the code outputs the following into the terminal:

```
# A tibble: 366 × 45
    yday `1977-1978` `1978-1979` `1979-1980` `1980-1981` `1981-1982` `1982-1983`
   <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1          NA        9.23        5.86        5.63        4.21        2.14
 2     2          NA        9.10        3.20        1.58        6.92        6.33
 3     3          NA        5.57        3.05        5.55        6.46        2.91
 4     4          NA        5.28        7.62        7.49       13.0        11.7 
 5     5          NA        7.87        1.58        9.23       10.3         9.67
 6     6          NA        8.00        1.13        2.34        3.30        9.02
 7     7          NA       12.5         4.98       10.3         2.09        7.13
 8     8          NA       10.6         1.86       12.7        10.3         7.40
 9     9          NA        7.79        2.76        6.23        7.98        3.15
10    10          NA        3.83        1.21        3.99        2.02        2.94
# … with 356 more rows, and 38 more variables: `1983-1984` <dbl>, `1984-1985` <dbl>,
#   `1985-1986` <dbl>, `1986-1987` <dbl>, `1987-1988` <dbl>, `1988-1989` <dbl>,
#   `1989-1990` <dbl>, `1990-1991` <dbl>, `1991-1992` <dbl>, `1992-1993` <dbl>,
#   `1993-1994` <dbl>, `1994-1995` <dbl>, `1995-1996` <dbl>, `1996-1997` <dbl>,
#   `1997-1998` <dbl>, `1998-1999` <dbl>, `1999-2000` <dbl>, `2000-2001` <dbl>,
#   `2001-2002` <dbl>, `2002-2003` <dbl>, `2003-2004` <dbl>, `2004-2005` <dbl>,
#   `2005-2006` <dbl>, `2006-2007` <dbl>, `2007-2008` <dbl>, `2008-2009` <dbl>, …
```

Where the NAs show up at the end.

##### Edit 1

The following is another way to do it which is less messy, but puts the NAs on the 29th of Feb each year.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    dyear = paste(
      floor(quarter(dates, type = "year.quarter", fiscal_start = 4)) - 1,
      ceiling(quarter(dates, type = "year.quarter", fiscal_start = 4)) - 1,
      sep = "-"
    ),
    day = day(dates),
    month = factor(month(dates), levels = c(4:12, 1:3))
  ) %>% 
  select(-dates) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dyear, values_from = observations) %>% 
  arrange(month)
```

I prefer this personally, since it seems clear that you are not preparing this data for a graph, and as a table, this explains more.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply split rainfall data at the `cumsum` of `'04-01'`. This gives a list `S` with 365 or 366 measures. Just adapt all `` `length<-` `` to 366, where `NA` is added in case. Finally just `cbind` and add `day` column. The column names for the years can be generated using `strftime`.

At first we need to expand the missing start and end, i.e. April 1 before your measures start and March 31 after, and `merge` it to the data.

```
aux <- data.frame(
    date=seq.Date(as.Date("1977-04-01"), as.Date("1982-03-31"), 'day')
)

dat <- merge(dat, aux, all=TRUE)
```

### Solution 1, more rows for leap years

```
S <- split(dat$rainfall, cumsum(strftime(dat$date, '%m-%d') == '04-01'))
yrs <- unique(strftime(dat$date, '%Y'))
yrs <- apply(cbind(yrs[-length(yrs)], yrs[-1]), 1, \(x) 
             paste(x[[1]], substr(x[[2]], 3, 4), sep='_'))
res1 <- cbind(day=1:366, setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(S, `length<-`, 366)),
                                             yrs))
```

**Gives:**

```
tail(res1)
#     day    1977_78    1978_79   1979_80    1980_81 1981_82
# 361 361  81.199690 110.382115  75.45856 134.532854      NA
# 362 362   1.713985   5.091447  13.14269   7.704723      NA
# 363 363   1.724329  37.100737  96.13059  42.934299      NA
# 364 364 113.334633  20.346748  97.99042  73.300045      NA
# 365 365 102.177311  30.465944 341.11990 133.788648      NA
# 366 366         NA         NA 235.38249         NA      NA
```

### Solution 2, all rows 366

If we want the days to be aligned through the years, we could `append` an `NA` after day `334` in non-leap years.

```
r <- by(dat, cumsum(strftime(dat$date, '%m-%d') == '04-01'), \(x) {
    rf <- x$rainfall
    yrs <- unique(strftime(x$date, '%Y'))
    yrs <- paste(yrs[1], substr(yrs[2], 3, 4), sep='_')
    if (length(rf) != 366) {
      rf <- append(rf, NA, 334)
    }
    `attr<-`(rf, 'yrs', yrs)
})

res2 <- cbind(day=1:366, setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame, r), sapply(r, attr, 'yrs')))
```

**Gives**

```
res2[331:337, ]
#     day   1977_78   1978_79   1979_80   1980_81 1981_82
# 331 331  47.65507  99.59559  38.80979 126.29785      NA
# 332 332  87.92888 125.35296  46.02958  82.03465      NA
# 333 333  28.98329  29.83954  31.30135  87.30667      NA
# 334 334 279.30901  39.37710  12.03988 283.37096      NA
# 335 335        NA        NA 206.63815        NA      NA
# 336 336  48.48830 108.82812  45.95315  36.61144      NA
# 337 337  16.72346  25.30704  36.15601 210.51755      NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(
    date=seq.Date(as.Date('1978-01-01'), as.Date('1981-12-31'), 'day')
)
set.seed(42)
dat$rainfall <- rnorm(nrow(dat), 20, 100) |> abs()
```